# vim: how to open multiple files into different tabs

Tags: vim

Let's assume I have a folder with source code files. I want to open certain files with vim.

Can I do it, so vim already put's them into different tabs?
(Just as like opening a folder in VS Code or any other text editor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vim -p /path/to/src/project/*.cpp`

If you expect to have a large number of files open at once in this manner, add a line akin to this to your `.vimrc`:

```
set tabpagemax=20
```

I believe the default is closer to ten.

Answer (score 2):

From `man vim`

> -p[N]   Open N tab pages. When N is omitted, open one tab page for each file

So I would recommend `vim -p /directory/*`